# Advance search error in magento

Tags: magento

I am facing problem while doing advance search in magento. I am getting following error.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND `s`.`store_id`='1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `relevance`=VALUES(`relevance`' at line 1
```

I am simply executing `<URL>/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?category=7`

PLease guide

Answer (score 0):

I see the same error in Magento EE 1.10.0.1
The solution was to change in the admin, then catalog, the search options to Mysql Fulltext, and instead of like, also fulltext, then the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.. But i resolve the error by another way. For my case , I needed to show FILTER box in side bar, but its not supported in Magento so I commented that block and it worked for me.